# Google analytics loses the track of referrer when directed to mobile website

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, google-analytics

I have a website www.xxxxx.com that directs the visitor to www.xxxxx.com/mobile if the visitor is on a mobile. I use a javascript code to detect if they are on mobile and direct them to the mobile subfolder. the code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 if (screen.width <= 679) {
   window.location = "http://www.xxxxx.com/mobile/";
}
//-->
</script>
```

All works well but the problem is that google analytics doesn't keep the original referrer to the main site if the visitor is directed to the mobile. For instance if a customer searchs for X company and comes to our www.xxxxx.com from a mobile and they are directed to www.xxxxx.co/mobile, google analytics shows this visitor as a "Direct" instead of showing the "Referrer Website" or the searched keywords.

How can I see the original referrer and the searched keywords please?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Google's documentation on [Causes for self-referrals > Redirects and Self-referrals](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3198398?hl=en):

> **meta refresh and javascript based redirects**
>
> Non server-side invoked redirects such as the meta refresh html tag or
>   javascript window.location methods may hide or obscure referrer
>   information from Google Analytics, therefore we don’t recommend using
>   such methods on any page that is likely to be a landing page.

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you recommend another way of directing people on mobile to our mobile website? Making a responsive website would be too much work at the moment I think. I hope there is a way to direct without losing the track of original referrers.

Comment: I would take a look at doing a server-side redirect. Do a Stackoverflow search :)